# BS3 -webkit-transform set on .modal-dialog removes copy-paste from context menu. Huh?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Codemirror 2 instance running inside a Bootstrap 3 modal dialog. There is a little piece of css that is causing an issue:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

This css prevents the context menu from having the copy / cut / paste options. Simply changing it to the following restores the options:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

In either case, using keyboard shortcuts to copy paste works. I can just hack this by overriding the styles, but I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can you post a (non-)working example?